# Permission to Access Primary Storage Denied in Android

Tags: android

I want to store a file in external storage, the code works fine for android version below Oreo, it requires to grant permission for Oreo and above versions.
Below is my code:

```
 int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity) ctx,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("per", "Permission to record denied");

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) ctx,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity) ctx);
            builder.setMessage("Permission to access the SD-CARD is required for this app to Download PDF.")
                    .setTitle("Permission required");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.i("click", "Clicked");
                    makeRequest();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            makeRequest();
        }
    }
     protected void makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) ctx,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
        file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
        downloadFilePathHash);

 }
```

the error I get:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, Look into [RxPermissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions). It puts the whole permission management into one builder pattern. Make sure you have RxJava dependency mentioned in your `build.gradle`

Also Coming to your issue, you should do this part :

`file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

in `onActivityResult` after the user has responded to your request